# Android - Dotted vertical line drawable width

Tags: android, view

Am creating vertical line with dashed. placed View/ImageView width 5dp or some thing and width 100dp and with this its not showing vertical dashed line. if i placing 100dp-height and 100dp-width then its showing dashed line. so it is occupying 99dp empty space

i need dashed line with 2dp or 5dp width and 100dp height

[image]

Here is my code:

**dash_line.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90">
    <shape
        android:shape="line">

        <stroke
            android:color="@color/white"
            android:dashWidth="10px"
            android:dashGap="10px"
            android:width="1dp"/>
        <size android:height="300dp" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

and

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dash_line"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take image of dash + space very tiny image (we can repeat that image) like this,

> repeat_background.xml (in Drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_repeat_image"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

> Now,

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/repeat_background"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

OR

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/repeat_background"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

So you can achieve this by little different way but nice efficient way !

Hope it will help you !

Comment: its not repeating bitmaps

Comment: try edited answer with view ! and let me know if it will help !